# Replacing elements and removing all elements

Tags: python

I am currently trying to figure out how to fill a list with one given element, overriding the rest of the elements in a list. so completely replacing every element in a given list with only 1 element.
How can i fill a list with zeroes, overwriting all elements in the list?

for the list values = [1,2,3,4,5] is there a way to make it so the list is values = [0,0,0,0,0]

and is there a way to remove all elements from a list? 
so for values = [1,2,3,4,5] make it values[] ?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x[:] = [0] * len(x)
>>> x
[0, 0, 0]
```

Explanation: the left hand side is a slice over all indices, assigning to slices is allowed, and the right hand side is a nice syntax for producing a list of repeated elements.

---

On a related note, don't ever do this:

```
>>> a = [[0] * 5] * 5
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Because then things like this will happen:

```
>>> a[0][0] = 3
>>> a
[[3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: do list index values have to be integers??

Comment: @expertinthemaking22 the indices are integers, the values (the contents of the list) can be anything.

Comment: @AlexHall Removed my answer you were correct thanks for the article. "Try to use map(), filter() or reduce() to replace an explicit for loop, but only if you can use a built-in function: map with a built-in function beats for loop, but a for loop with in-line code beats map with a lambda function!"

Answer (score 0):

1. list comprehension with no function - just the replacement element.
2. use clear() or just overwrite with a new, empty list, i guess.

   ```
   x = [1, 2, 3]
   [0 for elem in x]
   x.clear()
   ```

Answer (score -1):

To replace all elements in a list with one value:

```
values = [0] * len(values)
```

This repeats the `0` as many times as is needed to make up the length of the list, and then assigns this to `values`. Do **not** use this method with a mutable object like a custom class!

---

To empty a list, assign the name to an empty list:

```
values = []
```

Comment: `values = ...` does not change the original list object.

Comment: No, but it overwrites the name `values` with an empty list, which appears to be what OP is asking for. The end result is the same. Please correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: The difference is that if I run `values_copy = values` before your code, then `values_copy` will remain as the original list.

Comment: do list index values have to be integers?